# Named captures in gsub

Tags: ruby

I have the following piece of code, which is working correctly:

```
line.gsub!(%r{margdat= (\d+/\d+/\d+)}, 'stamp=CONVERT(date, \1,103)')
```

However, for reasons of code style, I prefer to use named captures. At the moment - it looks too "perl like" for me. I've tried this sort of thing:

```
line.gsub!(%r{margdat= (?<date>\d+/\d+/\d+)}, "stamp=CONVERT(#{date}, \1,103)")
```

But it just complains the variable doesn't exist. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `'stamp=CONVERT(date,  \k<date>, 103)'`?

Comment: That's how you can retrieve the value of the named group, but I don't understand the reference to 'date' in your replacement string.

Comment: The answer from Cary is correct. For some reason - I can't mark it as such.

Comment: Ha! Because it's a comment. I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
'stamp=CONVERT(date, \k<date>, 103)'
```